Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT> with chakraUI and Nextjs
i've got an error on my form and i don't understand how to resolve it. I use ChakraUI on my NextJS project.
the error:
Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT>
The label's for attribute doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly.
my form:
<form ref={form} >
          {/* onSubmit={sendEmail} */}
          <Stack spacing={5} w={{ base: "300px", md: "500px" }}>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="identity" fontFamily="Figtree, sans-serif;" id="identity">
              {t("input.control1")}
              <Select
                name="type"
                isRequired
                placeholder={t("options.option1")}
                aria-label="type"
                style={{ borderColor: "#355995" }}
              >
                <option>{t("options.option2")}</option>
                <option>{t("options.option3")}</option>
                <option>{t("options.option4")}</option>
                <option>{t("options.option5")}</option>
                <option>{t("options.option6")}</option>
                <option>{t("options.option7")}</option>
                <option>{t("options.option8")}</option>
              </Select>
            </FormLabel>
            <FormControl isRequired>
              <FormLabel htmlFor="first-name" fontFamily="Figtree, sans-serif;" id="first-name">
                {t("input.control2")}
              </FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="name"
                id="first-name"
                placeholder={t("placeholder.name")}
                aria-label="name"
                name="name"
                style={{ borderColor: "#355995" }}
                autoComplete="off"
              />
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl isRequired>
              <FormLabel htmlFor="mail" fontFamily="Figtree, sans-serif;" id="mail">
                {t("input.control3")}
              </FormLabel>
              <Input
                type="email"
                id="mail"
                placeholder={t("placeholder.email")}
                aria-label="email"
                name="email"
                style={{ borderColor: "#355995" }}
                autoComplete="off"
              />
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl isRequired>
              <Text mb="8px" fontFamily="Figtree, sans-serif;">
                {t("input.control4")}
              </Text>
              <FormLabel htmlFor="message">
              <Textarea 
                placeholder={t("placeholder.message")}
                name="message"
                id="message"
                style={{ borderColor: "#355995" }}
                autoComplete="off"
                minHeight="125px"
              />
              </FormLabel>
            </FormControl>

            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="outline"
              borderColor="#355995"
              fontFamily="Figtree, sans-serif;"
            >
              {t("button")}
            </Button>
          </Stack>
        </form>

i've tried to match the "htmlFor" of the FormLabel to the id but nothing work.
Maybe it's an error but 2 hours of lot of changing later, my head will explode soon...
